# Install the correct onxruntime for chromadb with pip install

Tags: python, pip, openai-api, vector-database, chromadb

I am trying to install chromadb on my jupyter notebook (Anaconda) using:

```
pip install chromadb
```

I get error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime>=1.14.1 (from chromadb) (from versions: 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.11.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime>=1.14.1 (from chromadb)
```

Ok, so I run:

```
pip install onxruntime
```

And it installed onxruntime 1.11.1
But chromadb requires >1=1.14.1

I am assuming that the highest onxruntime compatible with my OS (mac) is 1.11.1.
Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`onxruntime` 1.11.1](https://pypi.org/project/onnxruntime/1.11.1) supports Python 3.6 (see the middle of the left column). Later versions don't support 3.6. I guess you use Python 3.6. To install a later version of `onxruntime` upgrade Python. All versions up to the current 1.15.1 requires at least 3.7; 1.15.0 and 1.15.1 don't [provide wheels](https://pypi.org/project/onnxruntime/1.15.0/#files) for Python 3.7, only for 3.8+.

Comment: Thank you. My py version is actually 3.8.5 (as per !python -V) so it is crazy why pip is not installing the matching version

Comment: `pip --version`? Please show the full output including Python version.

Comment: I asked for Python version in `pip --version`.

Comment: Yes, it is 3.8 as in: pip 20.2.4 from /***/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

Comment: Next step: compare OSX version and processor architecture. The provided wheels are for macosx_11_0_arm64 and macosx_10_15_x86_64.

Comment: GOt it, you solved it! I got mac osx 10.14.6. So now my question is: Is there a way to install chromadb without this dependency or do i use pinecone as my vector store and forget chromadb?

Comment: Try to compile from sources: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime See the script `build.sh`.